# page : paginate :: paragraph :?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a verb that means "to typographically format a paragraph" the same way that `paginate` means "to typographically format a page"?  I'm inclined to coin `paragraphinate`.

Comment: Typographic paragraphing is way too new to get a special form of the verb. Simple _to paragraph_, zero-derived like most English verbings, does the trick when needed.

Comment: Paginate as in applying numbers to pages? A verb for applying numbers to paragraphs?

Comment: If you mean the process of deciding where to put the line breaks, that is called "line breaking" or "linebreaking" in typesetters' jargon.  "Justification" is also sometimes used but strictly speaking that refers to the process of stretching spaces to make the right-hand margin a straight line.  "Hyphenation" is the related process of deciding where *within a word* it is acceptable to split it across lines (when linebreaking would like to do so).

Comment: The modern meaning of paginate is [divide (content) into discrete pages, either electronic pages or printed pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination). Saying "typographically format a page" calls to mind more of the process of setting margins, headers, footers etc., and I've never heard it used that way. Regardless, I think your new coinage works well for this use case: *"Dang son, paragraphinate that [wall-o-text](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wall%20of%20text)!"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

page : paginate :: paragraph : paragraphize

> **paragraphize**, v.intr : to be formed into paragraphs. *1986 Simply Stated (Document Design Centre) Jan. 4/1  John Turrel hoped his comments ‘paragraphized well for Simply Stated’.*

OED also gives these forms:

> **paragraph**, v.trans : to divide or arrange (a text) into paragraphs. *1983 W. T. Stafford in Henry James: Novels 1871–80 1283   These two sentences..are punctuated and paragraphed in this printing to indicate that the words are Valentin's.*
>
> **paragraphing**, n : The arrangement or division of a text into paragraphs. *1992 N. Postman Technopoly iv. 62   Pagination led inevitably to more accurate indexing..which..was accompanied by innovations in..paragraphing, title-paging, and running heads*